# Long IF Statement.. Getting mixed up between OR and AND

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm getting so confused on why this isn't working:

```
if( ( ! $listing_info && $listing_info['status'] !== $this->get_approved()) || $listing_info['user_id'] !== $this->auth->get_user_id() || $listing_info['user_group'] !== $this->get_admin()) {
    return false;
}
```

Ok so my dilemna is these requirements. A user is viewing a listing.

- If the listing exists and it's an approved listing, show it to the user
- If the listing exists, but is not approved, do not show to user
- If the listing exists, but is not approved, but the logged in user is either admin or the person who created it, show it

So listing will show upon these qualifications:

- listing exists and is approved
- owner of listing can see the listing regardless of it's status
- admin can see all listings regardless of it's status

Any help on this would be fantastic... I can't figure it out =(

Comment: If you've got that many different criteria that you're confusing yourself, consider breaking it down into nested if statements. It's a little more typing, but much easier to debug. And consider how confusing it's going to look when you come back to it six months from now....

Comment: So, what doesn't work about it?  What scenario does it "not work" on?

Comment: It fails on if the user is not the sole user, but the status is approved and the listing exists. It still returns false

Comment: I'm not fond of nested IF statements because they can look pretty ugly... but I guess I could go down that route if that's better coding standards?

Comment: What are you trying to check with the first part (`( ! $listing_info && $listing_info['status'] !== $this->get_approved())` )? `!` applied to `$listing_info` as far as I remember PHP...

Comment: $listing_info just holds the array of data. So I'm checking if $listing_info does not return results AND the status does not equal approved. I just went with what @andrewsi said..

Comment: I think your situation is the following :                          `if (listing_exist AND (approved_listing OR is_Admin OR is_owner ) ){
 show listing
}else{
 not show listing
}`    i.e `if( isset($listing_info) && ( ( $listing_info['status'] == $this->get_approved() ) ||  ( $listing_info['user_id'] == $this->auth->get_user_id() ) || ( $listing_info['user_group'] == $this->get_admin() ) ) )`

Answer (score 0):

When things get confusing it's best to break things down, and use my favorite trick that drives some mathematicians crazy: use unnecessary parens and line breaks!

Now, your logical AND and OR simply won't work as you might expect...in fact, it's hard to know what to expect at all without revisiting some language specifications. But this is like having to rely on a proper order of operations listing in math - we're programmers, so forget that jazz - more parens and white space! Lets get rid of the unqualified "not" (!) usage to make it more explicit, because this is already kind of confusing.

```
if(
    $listing_info != true && (
        ( $listing_info['status'] !== $this->get_approved() ) || 
        ( $listing_info['user_id'] !== $this->auth->get_user_id() ) ||
        ( $listing_info['user_group'] !== $this->get_admin() ) )
    ) 
{
    return false;
}
```

So, the logic here is much clearer...and probably wrong.

First of all, the parens now make it clear that this a two condition thing - the listing info itself must not be true (huh? I get the feeling this is a typo), and the next condition must return TRUE. To get to this place, at least something inside the 3 OR conditions must return as true.

Another issue with clarity is that everything is being stated in the negative, and that makes a person's head hurt. Humans don't think like that by default, so it's easy to get confused. It is generally better to write:

```
if ($control == false)
```

than to write:

```
if ($control != true)
```

...because cognitively the first requires less mental computation, even if a computer could care less which one you choose. This is not a big deal in the simple case, but when you start building such branching logic and nesting AND and OR conditions, it gets confusing fast. I save the PHP-style !$condition for single logic only, personally.

If you can't because it doesn't make sense, as with your OR statements perhaps, just understand it's going to be harder to think about and use other tricks to make it easier to understand at a glance.

Now, to be clear, if you had simply broken it all up into the - admittedly - ugly branching if statements, you'd find it far easier to spot logical problems and could fix the bug much faster. If nothing else, debuggers naturally go line by line, and with it all stuffed into one if loop it is exceedingly hard to find out just what on earth happened. With branching logic you can much more easily "watch" line by line how the logic plays out based on varying inputs.

If I may offer one of my personal coding philosophies:

> First, do it ugly. 
>   Then, when it works, make it pretty. 
>   But don't forget - sometimes ugliness merely masks true beauty.

Once something works it is just always easier to make it pretty. But if something is pretty and non-working, it's always going to get ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You already broke your problem down into the specific conditional cases, so instead of using a hard to track if/then concept, just model your cases as functions and get some easy to read, functionally correct, and importantly: easy to debug code in return:

```
function renderListing($isadmin) {
  // render the listing, if $isadmin is true, with some admin controls
}

function showListing() {
  if($user->isAdmin()) {
    renderListing(true);
    // due to the additional requirements you already know, this
    // if block and the next one that uses renderListing cannot
    // be replaced with a single renderListing($user->isAdmin())
  }

  else if($listing->isApproved()) {
    renderListing(false);
  }

  //else do nothing, or render a placeholder, or an empty something, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return ( isset($listing_info) && (
           $listing_info['status'] == $this->get_approved() ||
           $listing_info['status'] != $this->get_approved() &&
             ( $listing_info['user_id'] == $this->auth->get_user_id() ||
               $listing_info['user_group'] == $this->get_admin() )
                                 ) );
```

might do the job. It can be simplified by removing the redundant approval check (it will be in the id/group check section only if not approved):

```
return ( isset($listing_info) && (
           $listing_info['status'] == $this->get_approved() ||
           $listing_info['user_id'] == $this->auth->get_user_id() ||
           $listing_info['user_group'] == $this->get_admin()
                                 ) );
```

I don't know if you need ===/!=== comparisons or just ==/!=. Of course, if this works, it should be thoroughly commented to explain it, or by next week you'll have forgotten how it works.